# My navbar kind of overlaps when you zoom in on the page and another issue detailed below

Tags: html, css, navbar

My navigation bar for some reason overlaps when I zoom in on the screen or change the scale of the page. I thought putting in "flex-wrap: nowrap" would solve that but it doesnt.

And also when I zoom in or scale the page, the navbar is no longer attached to the slideshow element below it as it is in full screen. Any help with these two issues would be greatly appreciated.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*MyStyle.css*/

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;


}

.third-level-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -190px;
    width: 190px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.third-level-menu>li {
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #6640C1;
    background: #6640C1;
}

.third-level-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: gold;
}

.second-level-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.second-level-menu>li {
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #6640C1;
    background: #6640C1;
    width: 100%;
}

.second-level-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: gold;
}

.top-level-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;

}

.top-level-menu>li {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    /* width: 273.2px; */
    background: #6640C1;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;

}

.top-level-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: gold !important;
}

.top-level-menu li:hover>ul {
    /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
    display: inline;


}


/* Menu Link Styles */

.top-level-menu a

/* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
    {
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    background: #6640C1;


    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display: block;
    line-height: 45px;
}

.top-level-menu a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: gold;
}


.container1 {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;

}


.gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 5%;
    float: left;
    width: 390px;


}

.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 5%;

}

.gallery:hover {
    transform: scale(1.03);
}

.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    ;
}


#main-title {
    font-family: 'Alfa Slab One', cursive;
    color: black;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -20px;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}


.container2 {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.announcement {
    display: inline-block;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: gold;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  



.mySlides {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;


}

.moving-images {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -4%;



}

/* Caption text */
.text {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 2px 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;

}

.active {
    background-color: #717171;
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .text {
        font-size: 11px
    }
}




.title-block {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    font-family: 'Alfa Slab One', cursive;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0px;
    height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

:root {
    --line-thickness: 0.1em;
    --glass-size: 50%;
    --icon-height: 2.5rem;
    --transition-speed: 0.15s;
    --timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.66, 1.51, 0.77, 1.13);
    --icon-color: black;
}




.search-icon {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    max-width: 20em;
    transition: all var(--transition-speed) linear, border-color 0s linear var(--transition-speed);
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 400px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid var(--line-thickness);
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding: 0.25em;
}

.search-icon__wrapper {
    width: var(--icon-height);
    height: var(--icon-height);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: all 0 linear;
}

.search-icon__wrapper:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search-icon__input {
    background: none;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    width: calc(90% - (var(--icon-height) / 2 + 1rem));
    margin-right: 6rem;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition: all var(--transition-speed) linear;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    color: black;


}

.search-icon__input::placeholder {
    color: grey;
}

.search-icon__glass {
    width: var(--glass-size);
    height: var(--glass-size);
    border: solid var(--line-thickness);
    border-color: var(--icon-color);
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    transition: all var(--transition-speed) var(--timing-function) var(--transition-speed), border-color 0s linear var(--transition-speed);
}

.search-icon__handle {
    height: calc(100% - var(--glass-size));
    width: var(--line-thickness);
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: var(--icon-color);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: all var(--transition-speed) var(--timing-function);
    transition-delay: var(--transition-speed);
}

.search-icon__handle::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: inherit;
    background: var(--icon-color);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: all var(--transition-speed) var(--timing-function);
    transition-delay: 0s;

}

.search-icon.open {
    width: 200px;
    border-color: var(--icon-color);
    transition-delay: var(--transition-speed);
}

.search-icon.open .search-icon__input {
    transition-delay: var(--transition-speed);
}

.search-icon.open .search-icon__glass {
    width: 45%;
    height: 45%;
    transition: all var(--transition-speed) var(--timing-function) 0s, border-color 0s linear var(--transition-speed);
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.search-icon.open .search-icon__handle {
    bottom: calc(50% - (100% - var(--glass-size)) / 2);
    border-radius: 100px;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.search-icon.open .search-icon__handle::after {
    transition-delay: var(--transition-speed);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}



.container {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap:nowrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: baseline;
    background: #323132;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;


}

.items {
    background: transparent;
    order: 4;
    flex: 1 auto;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif; 
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}
.items a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #a2a4a7;
    
}

.items a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
}


.vertical-right-1 {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px 0;
    left: 20%;
    box-shadow: 0.2px 0.2px;
}

.fa-facebook {
    background: #3B5998;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
.fa-twitter {
    background: #55ACEE;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
.fa-instagram {
    background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 35% 90%, #fec564, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 0 140%, #fec564, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 0 -25%, #5258cf, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 20% -50%, #5258cf, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 100% 0, #893dc2, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 60% -20%, #893dc2, transparent 50%), radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 100% 100%, #d9317a, transparent), linear-gradient(#6559ca, #bc318f 30%, #e33f5f 50%, #f77638 70%, #fec66d 100%);
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin+Condensed:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pathway+Gothic+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alfa+Slab+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Acme&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Allerta&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyStyle.css" />
    <title>www.TheLeague.com</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="announcement">
            <p>Shop 20% Off All Jerseys!</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title-block">
            <div style="float:right; margin: 0 auto;">
                <div class=" search-icon" style="margin-right: 75px; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <input class="search-icon__input" placeholder="search ...">

                    <div class="search-icon__wrapper">
                        <div class="search-icon__glass"></div>
                        <div class="search-icon__handle"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="float:right; margin: 0 auto; width: 65px; margin-top: 30px;">
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: black"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"
                            style="font-size: 35px;"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div
            style="margin:0 auto; width:300px; padding: 1px 0 50px 0; font-size: 25px; font-family:'Alfa Slab One', cursive;">
            <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="TheLeague.html">
                <h1 style="color: black;">The<u>League</u></h1>
            </a>

        </div>



        <ul class="top-level-menu">
            <li><a href="home.html"><i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size: 20px;"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="shopall.html"><i class="fa fa-tag" style="font-size: 20px"></i> Shop All &#x25BC; </a>
                <ul class="second-level-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Jerseys</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gym Shorts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="customize.html"><i class="fa fa-flask" style="font-size: 20px;"></i> Customize</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="teams.html"><i class="fa fa-futbol-o" style="font-size: 20px;"></i> Teams &#x25BC;</a>
                <ul class="second-level-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Soccer</a>
                        <ul class="third-level-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Barcelona</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">PSG</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Real Madrid</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Basketball</a>
                        <ul class="third-level-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Golden State Warriors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Celtics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Chicago Bulls</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Football</a>
                        <ul class="third-level-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">New England Patriots</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ravens</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Atlanta Falcons</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            <li><a href="contactus.html"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px;"></i>
                    Contacts Us</a>
            </li>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <div class="slideshow-container moving-images" data-pause="hover">

            <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="https://images.daznservices.com/di/library/sporting_news/a/fe/kobe-bryant-041315-getty-ftrjpg_hnmwtxmeqtvu1fyv5fnzn6abh.jpg?t=926331162&quality=100"
                    alt="kobe holding shirt" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="https://images.hdqwalls.com/download/lionel-messi-fc-art-1m-1366x768.jpg" style="width:100%">
                <!-- <div class="text">Caption Two</div> -->
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/tom-brady-new-england-patriots-football_21828_1366x768.jpg"
                    style="width:100%;">
                <!-- <div class="text">Caption Three</div> -->
            </div>
            <!-- <div style="text-align: center;">
                <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"><strong>&#10094; Prev</strong>
                </button>
                <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)"><strong>Next &#10095;</strong>
                </button>
            </div> -->
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center; margin: 10px;">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </div>


        <!-- JavaScript -->

        <script>
            var slideIndex = 1;
            showDivs(slideIndex);

            function plusDivs(n) {
                showDivs(slideIndex += n);
            }

            function showDivs(n) {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
                if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            }




            var slideIndex = 0;
            showSlides();

            function showSlides() {
                var i;
                var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
                for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                    slides[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                slideIndex++;
                if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
                for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }
                slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
                setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
            }
            const searchIcon = document.querySelector(".search-icon__wrapper");

            searchIcon.addEventListener("click", e => searchIcon.parentElement.classList.toggle("open"))
        </script>

        <!-- End of JavaScript -->

        <div style="margin: 30px;">
            <hr>
            </hr>
        </div>

        <br><br>
        <h3 style="text-align: center;font-size: 30px; color: black;font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif; ;">Featured
            Jerseys</h3><br><br><br>
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://www.teamzo.com/images/re-2019-2020-barcelona-home-nike-shirt-kids-messi-10-1559836177.png"
                    alt="The image shows the 2019-2020 Barcelona jersey">
                <div class="desc"> Barcelona 2019: Messi Jersey </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://fanatics.frgimages.com/FFImage/thumb.aspx?i=/productimages/_1768000/altimages/FF_1768829ALT1_full.jpg&w=900"
                    alt="The image shows the 2019-2020 Barcelona jersey">
                <div class="desc"> Golden State Warriors 2019: StephCurry Jersey </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://images.footballfanatics.com/FFImage/thumb.aspx?i=/productimages/_3775000/altimages/ff_3775300-29e956db2213fbdbcf67alt1_full.jpg&w=325"
                    alt="The image shows the 2019-2020 Barcelona jersey">
                <div class="desc"> Canucks 2019: Customizable Jersey </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://contestimg.wish.com/api/webimage/5e86c1d100c605394a614f9c-large.jpg?cache_buster=71f3e987b756bb4df19be721d299a68b"
                    alt="The image shows the 2019-2020 Barcelona jersey">
                <div class="desc"> Patriots 2019: Tom Brady Jersey </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://fanatics.frgimages.com/FFImage/thumb.aspx?i=/productimages/_3609000/altimages/ff_3609123-ef2947d2ef78011fbfc1alt3_full.jpg&w=600"
                    alt="The image shows the 2019-2020 Barcelona jersey">
                <div class="desc"> PSG 2019: Neymar Jersey </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0271/0975/2920/products/thumb.jpg?v=1580412625"
                    alt="The image shows the 2019-2020 Barcelona jersey">
                <div class="desc"> Lakers 2019: Kobe Bryant Jersey </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div style="margin: 30px;">
            <hr>
            </hr>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="items">
                <br><br>
                <p><a href="#" style="p">Find a Store</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">Sign Up For Email</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">Become A Member</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">Site Feedback</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="vertical-right-1" style="left: 25%; height: 90%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 20px 0; ">

            </div>
            <div class="items" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                <strong>
                    <p style="font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 20px; padding: 10px;">About The
                        League</p>
                </strong>
                <p><a href="#">News</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">Careers</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">Investors</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">Sustainability</a></p>
            </div>


            <div class="vertical-right-1" style="left: 50%; height: 90%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 20px 0; ">

            </div>

            <div class="items" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                <p style="font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;font-size: 20px; padding: 10px;">
                    <strong>Sports</strong></p>
                <p><a href="#">Soccer</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">Basketball</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">NFL</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">Tennis</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="vertical-right-1" style="left: 75%; height: 90%; margin: 10px auto;  ">

            </div>
            <div class="items" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                <p style="font-family: 'Cabin Condensed', sans-serif;font-size: 20px; padding: 10px;">Need To Talk?</p>
                <p><a href="#">Order Status</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">Shipping and Delivery</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">Returns</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">Payment Options</a></p><br>
                <p><a href="#">Contact Us</a></p><br>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>

            </div>


        </div>





    </main>
</body>





</html>
```

Try to change the scale of the page and youll see both these issues occurring, while at 100% zoom there dont seem to be any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have given to your slider a negative ´margin-top´ with percent units, so it will "adapt" (wrongly in this case) as the window height changes. Add the value in pixels and it will work. something like:

```
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -56px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that solved the problem regarding the detachment of the navbar from the slideshow container. Any idea about the navbar seeming to wrap when you zoom in?

Comment: I wouldn't  use `css flex` for a basic navbar. The old and easy `ul li {display-inline-block}` will give you less headaches. but the problem of your navbar is not about zooming in or out, is about not getting enough room for your elements. Use @media queries to make it adapt better.